# PHP - do IF checks on certain chars in a string to compare with from data in SQL db

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a suggestions tool: When the user types a char into a text field, the char gets sent off to a script (using AJAX) and is checked on in a SQL DB. If any entries in the DB match the users input, they get returned.

But I'm stuck on actually going through the users input string;

I need to check all characters one-by-one with each row in the DB.

So i was thinking:

1.) get the char length of the string and put it into `$string_count`

2.) define `$count=0;`

3.) do a while loop and make it stop when $count reaches over or equal to `$string_count`.

4.) inside that while loop: do another while loop and use condition: $det=mysql_fetch_array()

5.) then i could get the data (name) from row 1, and do a check to see if its first char matches the users input first char (which i don't know how to do).

6.)If it contains the correct char in the correct position, add the ID to a string with a comma after (`$possible.=$det['id'].",";`)

7.) Add one to $count (`$count++;`) in the parent while loop.

7.) that loop will go on, on every row, but obviously changing char each time, until there are no more chars to check...

I just wrote all that up from the top of my head, and now I'm lost. I think its completely wrong and there is a much easier way to do it? but can you guys just tell me if im on the right track?

I need to know how to do a check on a certain char in a string. So for example:

```
$my_str="my name is nav nav";
```

now i want to get the forth char in that string (which is "n").

any suggestions?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Can you clarify when you say, If any entries in the DB match the users input, they get returned. What do you mean by match?

Comment: So if every char in the name of that entry matches the user input string in the correct order, then information (the id) from that row will be fetched and returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$my_str="my name is nav nav";

$charAt= $my_str{3};

echo $charAt;

//outputs n (strings are 0 indexed)
```

EDIT:  Also wait until the user has input at least three characters and just do a database query using LIKE everytime:

```
SELECT * FROM example WHERE age LIKE '$userinput%'
```

http://www.htmlite.com/mysql011.php

(optimizing this is another story)

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your approach, but here's what I would do...

If the length of the user string is past a certain threshold (3 characters for example), send off the *entire* user input string to the DB via AJAX.

On the server side, run `SELECT * FROM example WHERE field LIKE CONCAT(?, '%')`. The ? represents a bound parameter to ensure you don't suffer from SQL injection issues. (See PHP's [PDO Docs](http://us.php.net/pdo) for more info on prepared statements)